# CSS: no DIV width when display set to none

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, width

I'm on the process of making a dropdown widget. The menu the expands down is set to the same width as the parent (using jQuery).

The widget is working as expected, until however, you place it inside a DIV container with inital display set to none. When this container is shown, all the dropdown width's according to jQuery are zero...
If the container is shown by default, all works.

Hopefully my fiddle will better illustrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ruFzR/
On the results pane; the top dropdown is outside of the container, the bottom inside it. Besides some obvious styling issues, the width is not expanding.

Comment: this can be simply done with css

Comment: Yep. I wouldn't go about a dropdown in this manner. At most, I would use js to do animation, or show/hide methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the width issue caused by `display: none;` by using `visibility: hidden;` instead.  Use `visibility: visible;` to make it visible.

The element stays within your content flow (same size, etc.) while it's simply invisible.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the width of something that's hidden and you can't un-hide it for whatever reason, you can clone it, change the CSS so it displays off the page, make it invisible, and then measure it.  The user will be none the wiser if it's hidden and deleted afterwards.

Example:

```
$itemClone = $('.hidden-item').clone().css({
        'visibility': 'hidden',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'z-index': '-99999',
        'left': '99999999px',
        'top': '0px'
    }).appendTo('body');
var width = $itemClone.width();
$itemClone.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

the .width() is processed by the browser that's why you get "0" try with the attribute instead

```
 $('#elt').attr('width');
```

Comment: That would read back the `width` attribute, but as you can see in his markup, he isn't setting one.

Answer (score 0):

From the example i am not sure what the problem is ..

But you should be set (*in that example*) with

```
.splitButton2 > div{width:100%;}
```

This is equivalent to the jQuery code you wrote, has no downsides (*width is 0 if the element is `display:none`, javascript dependency*) and is easier on the browser ..

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `display:none:` you have to show the menu first, calculate the width, then hide it. Alternatively, you could hide with absolute positioning, which should report the width correctly since the element has been painted. Example: `position: absolute; top: -999em;`