# Unable to get div width/height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqote

I found a good example of simple how to display a pop up near a click: http://roshanbh.com.np/examples/popup-message/

I'm leveraging this for my button click, but I can't seem to get an actual width or height of the element and I'm not entirely sure why:

```
function BindObject(o)
{
    o.click(function(e)
    {
        var editor = $(this).find(".object_editor");

        console.log(editor);
        console.log(editor.height());
    });
}
```

Here is what is printed to the console: [image]

(FYI only, BindObject is called on document ready, I am using jqote as well, not sure how relevant that is, it might be)

```
 $("#QuestContent").html($("#QuestTemplate").jqote(quest_data));
 $("#QuestContent").find(".object").each(function() {
    BindObject($(this));
 });
```

It obviously finds the element (represented by editor), but I'm unable to determine it's width or height. I do know that display is set to none, but that's because I don't want to display it until someone clicks a button to display the pop up. Anyone have any ideas why it's always null?

Here is the css:

```
.object_editor{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;   
    width:172px;
    height:102px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font: 14px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:#000000;
    display:none;
}
```

Edit: And the relevant jqote just in case it's needed:

```
<!-- Object Template -->
<script type="text/x-jqote-template" id="ObjectTemplate">
    <![CDATA[
        <span class="object <%= (this.hidden ? "hiddenType" : "") %>">&nbsp;
            <input class="objectType" type="hidden" name="<%= this.key[0] %>" value="<%= this.type %>">
            <input class="objectEntry" type="hidden" name="<%= this.key[1] %>" value="<%= this.entry %>">
            <a data-emptytext="<%= object_types[this.type] %>" data-name="<%= this.key[1] %>" target="_blank" href="<%= (this.entry? whUrl(this.type, this.entry) : "#") %>" class="objectName"><%= this.name %><%= (this.entry?" ("+this.entry+")":"") %></a>&nbsp;<i class="icon-edit editObject"></i>
            &nbsp;
            <% if(this.remove) { %>
                <a href=".object" class="deleteParent"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
            <% } %>
        </span>

        <!-- Insert our Editor -->
        <%=$("#ObjectEditorTemplate").jqote({type: this.type, entry:this.entry}) %>
    ]]>
</script>

<!-- Object Editor Template -->
<script type="text/x-jqote-template" id="ObjectEditorTemplate">
    <![CDATA[
        <div class="object_editor">My Editor: <%= this.entry %></div>
    ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Too add more info, the page may have more than one class called object_editor, but regardless that's why I use .find, so I don't think that should matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because display is set to none.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935023/css-no-div-width-when-display-set-to-none) for a similar question.

Comment: I tried using visibility: hidden; instead, but it still gives me a value of null when I do editor.width or editor.height

Comment: Once i moved it within the <span> it found it correctly, and I needed the above as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this
    `$('divID').css('width');`
similarly for height