# Table losing its width on display none/block

Tags: css, html

I am having a tabbed view with a table in each tab. By changin the tab the table is set to `display: none`. On clicking on the tab again the table will be set to `display: block`.

The problem is on clicking back on the tab, the table loses its width and shrinks.
I want the table to keep its original width. How to do this?

[image]
After changing the tab

[image]

Comment: When something is display:none, it no longer takes up space in the layout. If you want it to be invisible, but still take up space, you instead set `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible`.

Comment: No I want the table to take the original width on display: block, not on none

Comment: Please provide some code that showcases your issue, along with efforts made to solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: no DIV width when display set to none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935023/css-no-div-width-when-display-set-to-none)

Comment: No it's not working withe visibility, the size of the table changes on visibility:  visible;

Comment: Could you provide us with an image what do you really want ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Display:block` will change the by default behavior of the Table element which results in loosing its width. instead of that you can change `display:table`

Answer (score 0):

I have a table where th fields are sticky. When toggling display none/block, the sticky behavior is lost. none/table doesn't work either, but none/"" (the empty string) does. Tested on the usual browsers.